# How to write a clean code with free-marker template in multiple if and else blocks?

Tags: freemarker

I am new to free-marker template and in my template its seems that I might have to repeat a lot of if and else blocks with repetition of same if condition.
Is there a more convenient or cleaner way of writing this if block or instead of repeating them.

```
               <span > </span>
         <#elseif section.role?has_content && section.person?has_content && section.organisation??>
           <span > </span>
         <#elseif section.role?has_content && section.organisation?has_content && section.person??>
           <span > </span>
         <#elseif section.person?has_content && section.organisation?has_content && section.role??>
               <span > </span>
         <#elseif section.person?has_content && section.role?? && section.organisation??>
               <span > </span>
         <#elseif section.organisation?has_content && section.role?? && section.person??>
               <span > </span>
         <#elseif section.role?has_content && section.organisation?? && section.person??>
               <span > </span>
         </#if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think you can do something like this in freemaker which is much cleaner then repeating the conditions.
- Instead of repeating this `section.role?has_content` multiple times you can assign this condition value in a variable and use it later like this `<#assign hasRole = section.role?has_content />`

````
           <#assign hasRole = section.role?has_content />
           <#assign hasOrganisation = section.organisation?has_content />

           <span >
                <#if section.person?has_content><span ></span><#if section.role?has_content><span ></span></#if></#if>
                <#if section.role?has_content><span ></span><#if section.organisation?has_content><span ></span></#if></#if>
                <#if section.organisation?has_content>
                    <span ></span>

                </#if>
           </span>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can check all in a single if statement:

```
<#if section.person?? && section.role?? && section.organisation?? &&
(section.person?has_content || section.organisation?has_content || section.role?has_content)>
 <span ></span>
</#if>
```

Comment: thanks. I have different content to display on the condition's

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use <#switch> tag in order to handle multiple cases as in classic proggraming languages. Here is an example from freemarker.apache.org:

```
<#switch animal.size>
<#case "small">
    This will be processed if it is small
<#break>
<#case "medium">
    This will be processed if it is medium
<#break>
<#case "large">
    This will be processed if it is large
<#break>
<#default>
    This will be processed if it is neither
</#switch>
```

In your example, as I can see, you can accurately wrap your statements in multiple switch-cases, and use variables like Adam suggests you